# Horizontal Menu Not Displaying Inline

Tags: menu, internet-explorer-9

I'm having an issue with my horizontal menu. The menu is not displaying inline in IE9. It displays fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. Unfortunately I'm working on a Mac and don't have access to IE to test it. Do you have any ideas why it's not working correctly?

Here's my CSS:

```
.navigationwide {
    background-image: url('images/site_gray_bg.png');
    border-top: 3px solid #efa320;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.navigation {
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Medula One', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    color: #efa320;
}
/* ----------------- SUBMENU START ----------------- */
.menu li ul {
    background-image: url('images/site_gray_bg.png');
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
}
.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.menu li li {
    background: none;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li:hover li a {
    background: none;
}
.menu li ul a {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Medula One', cursive;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.menu li ul a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #efa320;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I googled and found the following link which might help with your inline question horizontal menu http://openegg.ca/creating-a-horizontal-menu/